# how to fetch the value of element through xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

```
I have a below XML.
XML-
<Book>
 <Title>blahblah</Title>
 <Title>
  <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>
  <subtitle>fgdh</subtitle>asdfg
 </Title>
 <Title>
  <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>jhuk
  <subtitle>xyza</subtitle>refsdw
 </Title>
<Title>
 <subtitle>bcdf</subtitle>fdgfjhdc
 <subtitle>trey</subtitle>
</Title>
```

I want to get below output through xslt,Can anyone please help me out to get this        resolved.

```
<Title>blahblah</Title>
<Title subtitle="bcdffgdh">asdfg</Title>
<Title subtitle="bcdfxyza">jhukrefsdw</Title>
<Title subtitle="bcdftrey">fdgfjhdc</Title>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Your question was down voted because you show no attempt at trying anything at all.

Comment: yes, you can use xslt 2.0 but it would be great if you can provide result in xslt 1.0

Comment: @kevin, I have attempted to resolve this, it is the complex one, it is not as simple as you are assuming it.

Comment: Really? Seems simple to me. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSL given your input (of course making it valid with an end book tag and also surrounding the output with the same tag ... is only one example of 100 ways to do what you asked, and it may not even be correct since in you trying things helps others to understand what you are really looking for and all the different possibilities.

Here's the XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <book>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </book>
    </xsl:template>    
    <xsl:template match="Title[child::subtitle]">
        <Title>
        <xsl:attribute name="subtitle">
            <xsl:for-each select="subtitle">
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:variable name="mixedtext">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::text()[not(parent::subtitle)]"/>    
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space($mixedtext),' ','')"/>
        </Title>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="Title">
            <Title>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </Title>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the output:

```
<book>
    <Title>blahblah</Title>
    <Title subtitle="bcdffgdh">asdfg</Title>
    <Title subtitle="bcdfxyza">jhukrefsdw</Title>
    <Title subtitle="bcdftrey">fdgfjhdc</Title>
</book>
```

Exactly as you asked (and by the way, not that difficult as you stated in your comment). Took 2 minutes.

Comment: great,,thanks a lot kevin, I was looking for "<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::text()[not(parent::subtitle)]"/>"

Comment: Or just use <xsl:apply-templates select="child::text()"/>